# How to check for a change in mac spaces?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I need code to run every time the user switches to a different space. So if a user goes from space 1 to 2, my desired method should be called. What would this go under. I looked under NSWorkSpace but didn't see anything applicable How do?

Answer (score 1):

You looked right past it. The notification you're looking for is `NSWorkspaceActiveSpaceDidChangeNotification`.